# WPF: Get rid of shadow in tab headers

Tags: wpf, shadow, tabitem

I have the following code:

```
     <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemStyle">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Chrome"
                                    BorderBrush="Blue" 
                                    Background="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                                  Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black"
                              BlurRadius="10"
                              Opacity="0.25"
                              ShadowDepth="4"
                              Direction="270" />
        </Grid.Effect>

        <TabControl Background="Transparent">
            <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}" Header="Tab 1" />

            <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}" Header="Tab 2" />
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

The grid has a DropshadowEffect which I need. 
The TabControl's background must be Transparent. 
I have a style for the TabItems which I need.

The style for the TabItems cause the tab headers to have a shadow. I don't want that shadow.

Is there a way to get rid of the shadow on the TabItem headers? 
But keep the shadow on the Grid.

Please help!

Best regards 
/Steffe

Comment: The grid will be filling the parent grid and behind the tabcontrol. It's only that grid seems to have a dropshadow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to apply the effect to a sibling `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black"
                              BlurRadius="10"
                              Opacity="0.25"
                              ShadowDepth="4"
                              Direction="270" />
        </Grid.Effect>
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemStyle">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Chrome"
                                    BorderBrush="Blue" 
                                    Background="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                                  Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TabControl Background="Transparent">
            <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}" Header="Tab 1" />

            <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}" Header="Tab 2" />
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Then it won't affect the `TabControl`.

Comment: @Mc_Topaz: Did you try this or what happened?